# SQL - create flag in query to highlight order which contain quantity = 1

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have tried creating a case statement but doesn't seem to give me what i want.  Id like to get a split of the table (which is at a product level) and aggregate at an order level of items which contain quantity of 1.

Any ideas on how I would do this?

```
order id | Product | Quantity 
---------+---------+--------------
 11111   | sdsd4   | 1 (single item )
 22222   | sasas   | 1 (multiple items)
 22222   | wertt   | 1 (multiple items)
```

I'd like to get a case statement to add another column to split out orders with quantity = 1 and orders greater 1

Any idea on how I would do this?

The desired outcome would be the column in (brackets)

I could then count the orders and bring in the newly created column as the dimension

More detail here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQRMh.png)

Attached is an image of table structure.

Logic, if quantity = 1 and 1 order then single item order
if order has one item but multiples of same item non single item order 
if order has more than one product then non single item order

Comment: Specify the expected result as well!

Comment: It is hard to understand your requirement because you are using terms that are unfamiliar to database engineers. Perhaps you can come up with sample data and the expected output, that would help.

Comment: Ive added desired outcome in pic above and logic.  hope this helps.

Comment: It is considered good practice to not use spaces in column names -- I use underscore (`_`) myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 
  CASE COUNT(DISTINCT Product) OVER(PARTITION BY order_id) 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Single Item Order'
    ELSE 'Multiple Items Order'
  END Single_or_Multiple
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 11111 order_id, 'sdsd4' Product, 1 Quantity UNION ALL
  SELECT 22222, 'sasas', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 22222, 'wertt', 1
)
SELECT *, 
  CASE COUNT(DISTINCT Product) OVER(PARTITION BY order_id) 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Single Item Order'
    ELSE 'Multiple Items Order'
  END Single_or_Multiple
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row order_id    Product Quantity    Single_or_Multiple   
1   11111       sdsd4   1           Single Item Order    
2   22222       sasas   2           Multiple Items Order     
3   22222       wertt   1           Multiple Items Order
```

Comment: Nailed it!  

Brilliant Thanks very much for your help.  

And for everyone who responded.

Comment: glad it worked for you. also consider voting up the answer if it helped you :o)

Answer (score 3):

If your database supports analytic functions, then you can use a query like this one:

```
SELECT *,
      CASE WHEN count("Product") OVER (partition by "order id") > 1
      THEN 'multiple items' ELSE 'single item'
      END As "How many items"
FROM Table1
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b659279fc16d2084cb1cf4a3bea361a1

Comment: The database im using is BigQuery

Comment: Hi, I tried this but didnt return the desired outcome.

Comment: This answer looks correct to me and should run on BigQuery.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this right, you could use a subquery to get the count of records for an order and flag a record, if this count is larger then 1 and the quantity is equal to 1.

```
SELECT t1.order_id,
       t1.product,
       t1.quantity,
       CASE
         WHEN t1.quantity = 1
              AND (SELECT count(*)
                          FROM elbat t2
                          WHERE t2.order_id = t1.order_id) > 1 THEN
           'flag'
         ELSE
           'no flag'
       END flag
       FROM elbat t1;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply.

I think this is nearly there however, there is just 1 table so no need for a join?  

Sorry for the lack of info on this.  Im a newb

Comment: @sticky bit You explained a correct way to solve it via corelated subquery. I tried it a while ago but only was close `t2.order_id=t1.order_id` did the trick. But a simple suggestion would it be better if `group by`was used for count even I am a little unsure as group by would again aggregate but we want row by row. Any point on that ?